# Mingw компиляция с поддержкой __uint128

Tags: c++, mingw

Я использую MinGw64 в Windows 10, и испытываю трудности с компиляцией программы которая использует __uin128. Подскажите, какая именно версия поддерживает это расширение, и как собрать программу с его поддержкой?

Comment: Тип называется `__uint128_t`.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, но версии MinGw которые я не ставил, в том числе и TDM64, все они выдают ошибку, что не находят этот тип

Comment: обсуждали это здесь [__uint128_t on mingw gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174419/uint128-t-on-mingw-gcc) Если очень хочется, напишите свою структуру с двумя uint64_t и сэмулируйте.

Comment: На моем [GCC из MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) все работает.